# 2.7 hidden object problems to 2.8

Tags: visibility

in 2.7 my file the items were saved hidden 2.8 the same items are not unable to be unhidden. it is a lot of work and put in this and if you tell me how to fix and/or update to repair this problem would be nice

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called "enable in the view-port" when you right-click a collection.
Try using that.
[image: view-port display]